# Flutter I have a specific json parsing requirement please correct my code. I have used groupBy Listing etc while parsing

Tags: json, flutter

In flutter I have a specific json parsing requirement which involves groupBy Listing  as I want to List the items with specific conditions and mark them while showing the output with that status colour and shape.
My json looks like

```
{
  "data1": [
    {
      "ID": 6,
      "AwardId": 3,
      "SemesterYear": 2022,
      "SemesterDetails": {
        "Details": [
          {
            "SemesterID": "5",
            "SemesterName": "Sem1",
            "Status": "LIVE"
          },
          {
            "SemesterID": "6",
            "SemesterName": "Sem2",
            "Status": "YET TO COME"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ID": 4,
      "AwardId": 3,
      "SemesterYear": 2021,
      "SemesterDetails": {
        "Details": [
          {
            "SemesterID": "3",
            "SemesterName": "Sem1",
            "Status": "COMPLETED"
          },
          {
            "SemesterID": "4",
            "SemesterName": "Sem2",
            "Status": "COMPLETED"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "AwardId": 3,
      "SemesterYear": 2020,
      "SemesterDetails": {
        "Details": [
          {
            "SemesterID": "1",
            "SemesterName": "Sem1",
            "Status": "COMPLETED"
          },
          {
```

I want the ouput as shown in  the screenshot.
like i the first scren I have alreay achieved the Years List with Live status in green colour, secondly After the click of on that item  I need to show Semester names like Live
Sem1 in green

```
          YET TO COME
              Sem2  in orange colour                                               
   [out put image][1].  Below is my code as follows:
```

Please correct my code
flutter and dart code

```
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {

              final List<Details> listWithStatusLive = [];
              final List<Details> listWithStatusCompleted = [];
              final List<Details> listWithStatusYETTOCOME = [];

              for (var item in detailsList.details) {
                if (item.status == "COMPLETED") {
                  listWithStatusCompleted.add(item);
                }
                if (item.status == "LIVE") {
                  listWithStatusLive.add(item);
                }
                if (item.status == "YET TO COME") {
                  listWithStatusYETTOCOME.add(item);
                }

              }
              final Map<String, List<Details>> semesterGroupListByStatus =
              groupBy(detailsList.details, (Details key) => key.status);

              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0,),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text("Live"),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: listWithStatusLive.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),


                            child: new InkWell(
                              onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          HoDScreen())),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 60,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  color: Colors.green),
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(listWithStatusLive[index]
                                      .semesterName
                                      .toString())),
                            ),
                            ),

                          );
                        }),
                  //  Text("Live semester: ${listWithStatusLive.length.toString()} "),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                    ),
                    Text("Completed"),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: listWithStatusCompleted.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  color: Colors.orange),
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(listWithStatusCompleted[index]
                                      .semesterName
                                      .toString())),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                    ),
                    Text("YET TO COME"),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: listWithStatusYETTOCOME.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  color: Colors.orange),
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(listWithStatusYETTOCOME[index]
                                      .semesterName
                                      .toString())),
                            ),
                          );
                        })
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H291S.jpg
```

Comment: I am still waiting for somebosy to fix my query or issue ith json parsig uisng groupBy Listing in flutter

Comment: H any body please try to fix my query  of groupBy Listing and  required mapping to achieve my targets.